# Cannot find module 'ical'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm getting this error when I upload and test my AWS Lambda function.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'ical'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:2:14)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
  ]
}
```

Can you please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please Make sure node_moduels directory is readable

```
chmod -R +r node_modules
```